# Schale, Schüssel oder Napf

Tags: word-choice

Könnte mir jemand erklären, worin der Unterschied zwischen Schale, Schüssel und Napf besteht. Also z.B. von welchem Gefäß trinkt/frißt meine Katze, wo esse ich mein Müsli und was eignet sich für größere Mengen (beim Backen z.B.)

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch?

Comment: Schau mal selber rein ;) Hier hab ich bestimmt mehr erfahren

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Für jeden der drei Behälter gilt, dass seine Form in den meisten Fällen Ähnlichkeiten mit einer Kugelkalotte hat. (Man hackt mit einem großen Schwert eine Melone in zwei verschieden große Teile. Die Schale eines Melonenteils ist eine Kalotte.) Es gibt weder Griff noch Henkel.

---

### Schale

Die Schale ist von den Dreien der flachste Behälter. Es gibt Schalen, die rein dekorative Zwecke erfüllen, Schalen, die als Essgeschirr auf einem Tisch stehen können und Speisen für eine Person enthalten, und Schalen, die eine Zwischenform bilden. Darunter fallen die Obstschalen, die dekorativ sind, und zugleich Lebensmittel enthalten (jedoch nicht nur für eine Person)

Eine Schale kann z.B. als Müslischale dafür gedacht sein, Flüssigkeiten zu beinhalten, sie kann aber auch z.B. für Obst gedacht sein. Dann ist nicht unbedingt notwendig, dass sie dicht ist:

[image: Obstschale]
*Obstschale*

---

### Schüssel

Eine Schüssel sieht einer Schale sehr ähnlich, ist aber größer und tiefer. Während eine Suppenschale zum Essgeschirr gehört, und die Portion für eine Person enthält, enthält eine Suppenschüssel Suppe für mehrere Personen. In jede Schüssel können Flüssigkeiten gefüllt werden. Auch in der Küche, bei der Zubereitung von Speisen, kommen Schüsseln zum Einsatz (z.B. Rührschüssel).

Es gibt für manche Schüsseln auch Deckel, dann eignen sich diese Schüsseln auch als Aufbewahrungsbehälter. Z.B werden in der Gastronomie Reis, Kartoffeln, Suppen und andere Gerichte oftmals in größeren Mengen vorgekocht und dann in verschließbaren Schüsseln im Kühlraum aufbewahrt.

[image: Schüssel]
*Schüssel*

---

### Napf

Ein Napf hat ungefähr die Größe einer Schale, ist in der Regel aber deutlich tiefer. Näpfe verwendet man heutzutage fast ausschließlich, um Haustieren Nahrung und Wasser bereit zu stellen.

[image: Napf]
*Napf*

Comment: Deine Antworten werten jede noch so einfache Frage auf, woher hast du nur immer diese schönen Bilder. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Als „[Napf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Napf)“ bezeichnet man hauptsächlich das Gefäß, aus dem deine Katze frisst.

Die Unterscheidung von „Schüssel“ und „Schale“ ist schon etwas schwieriger und in der Alltagssprache wird kaum ein Unterschied zwischen beiden Gefäßen gemacht – beide Gefäße werden vor allem zur Aufbewahrung von Speisen benutzt.

Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schale_(Gef%C3%A4%C3%9F)) ist die Schale aber meist flacher als eine Schüssel. Deinen Müsli isst du demnach wohl in einer Schüssel. Beachte auch, dass im Oberdeutschen oder Österreichischen mit einer Schale auch eine „Tasse“ gemeint sein kann.